# Calendar control in Windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Please suggest a good calendar control which i can use in my app in windows phone 7.

My requirement is to change the background color of selected date and also have multi select option.

Comment: My intention was to get a Quick Calendar control in  windows phone 7 on which I could jump on to quickly without wasting my time building one afresh, i am basically a dotnet developer and not WP7 devoleper, i wanted to know from WP7 community is there a calendar control , Since Calendar Control is a basic control and every toolkit is most likely to have it. So i thought i am missing something and wanted to clarify it on this stage. But to my surprise, there is calendar control built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was in need of a calendar control, I had found these.

http://maheshprasad.blogspot.in/2010/12/calendar-control-for-windows-phone-7.html

http://wpcontrols.codeplex.com/

But I ended up making my own custom calendar.

Comment: how did you make you own custom calendar?

Comment: Made 7x6 row of buttons for calendar. And logic to populate the dates.

Answer (score 0):

our calendar should do what you want: http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/CalendarPhone/.
But it's not free